# Node-Red & The Things Network

Tags: node-red

I have been trying for most of the weekend to try and figure out how to retrieve data using Node-Red on a Raspberry Pi from the ‘Data Storage’ on The Things Network.

If I use Swagger, I can retrieve data, and as a first step, I am trying to replicate this functionality within Node-Red, but I can’t seem to get it working.

So far I have setup a simple flow:-

Inject => HTTP Get Request => Debug output.

I have tried setting various ways in the inject node, but no matter what I try and do I get ‘Not Authorised’. I’ve got the credentials
“Content-Type":"application/json”
"Authorization":"key ttn-account-v2.hKfO9VxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxfwZFU6G4A080s”

I’ve put these in the msg.header, the msg.payload, and others, without any really success.

I would really appreciate any ideas on how to get it to work.

Edit: As requested, here is info as to how I am setting the data.
The inject node has properties that are setting the msg.

[image: inject node properties].

I have tried a few different combinations, but no success.

Comment: Any reason why you are not using the TTN nodes? https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-ttn

Comment: Also edit the question to show how you are setting the headers.

Comment: Hi Hardillb, thanks for the quick response. I’m not using the node-red-contrib-ttn as the GitHub respository is deprecated and no longer updated.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the full JSON from both the `msg.payload` and the `msg.headers` (you can xxx out the password/key) But both Authorization and content-type want to be in the headers.

Comment: We also need to know what the errors are you get back

Comment: The only error I get is from the debug node attached to the end which reads <Not Authorized>

Comment: Hi, I am a little confused by your comment. Using the inject node, I think I have set msg.payload = {“Authorisation”:”key ttn-account ... “} and I think I have set msg.headers to {“Content-Type”:”application/json”}. The full JSON with a few xxx’s is sown above. I’ve done nothing more.

Comment: Both `Authorization` and `Content-Type` should be in `msg.headers`. As I said, please [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64199945/edit) the question to show the FULL JSON in the inject node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`msg.headers` should contain both the `Content-Type` and the `Authorization` values

e.g.

```
{
  "Authorization": "key ttn-account-v2.hKfO9VxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxfwZFU6G4A080s",
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
```

Comment: That is fantastic, I knew I had to be missing something simple. I had a few challenges getting the data in, but switching to Visual Editor and adding objects did the trick